# Ошибка в программе угадай число

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

я решил написать программу "угадай число" на Python. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

import random
num = random.randint(1,100)
def guess(entry):
    while True:
        guess = entry.get()
        i = int(guess)
        if i == num:
            messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Правильно!")
            break
        elif i > num:
            messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число меньше")
        elif i < num:
            messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число больше")
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Угадай число")
text = Label(tk,text="Введите число от 1 до 100")
text.pack()
num1 = IntVar()
entry = Entry(tk,width=50,textvariable=num1)
entry.pack()
btn = Button(tk,text="Отправить",command=guess)
btn.pack()
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=400,height=300,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
```

Но выдаёт ошибку:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: guess() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry'
```

Я перевёл ошибку, но не понимаю как это исправить.

Comment: "Не хватает одного аргумента". Ну как это можно исправить-то? Добавить аргумент.

Comment: @Эникейщик почти исправил, спасибо

Comment: @Эникейщик теперь при запуске всплывает окно загаданное число больше, хотя я даже ничего не вводил. И в форме число 0

Comment: Ну так любое число от 1 до 100 больше 0.

Comment: @Эникейщик а почему в форме сразу число 0? https://ibb.co/KjSGKwJ

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Всё, я исправил только теперь messagebox.showinfo нельзя закрыть

Comment: Наверное IntVar() по умолчанию инициализируется нулем, поэтому в форме сразу 0.

Comment: Всё я все исправил! Нужно было добавить break

Comment: @Эникейщик скорее всего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил это так:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
num = random.randint(1,100)
def guess():
while True:
    guess1 = num1.get()
    i = int(guess1)
    if i == num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Правильно!")
        break
    elif i > num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число меньше")
        break
    elif i < num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число больше")
        break
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Угадай число")
text = Label(tk,text="Введите число от 1 до 100")
text.pack()

num1 = IntVar()
entry = Entry(tk,width=50,textvariable=num1)
entry.pack()

btn = Button(tk,text="Отправить",command=guess)
btn.pack()

tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=400,height=300,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного поправил код. Вроде теперь как-то работает. Убрал цикл внутри `guess()`. Он там не нужен, т.к. делает бесконечный цикл на первом вводе. Плюс убрал в `guess()` переменную `entry`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

import random
num = random.randint(1,100)
def guess():
    #while True:
    val = entry.get()
    i = int(val)
    if i == num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Правильно!")
    elif i > num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число меньше")
    elif i < num:
        messagebox.showinfo("Ваш ответ", "Загаданное число больше")
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Угадай число")
text = Label(tk,text="Введите число от 1 до 100")
text.pack()
num1 = IntVar()
entry = Entry(tk,width=50,textvariable=num1)
entry.pack()
btn = Button(tk,text="Отправить",command=guess)
btn.pack()
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=400,height=300,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```